# Change some Path Parameters of an Akka Http service to Query Params

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http, spray

I have the following code that takes path parameters;

```
def candlesRange: Route = (path("candles" / Segment / Segment / IntNumber / LongNumber / LongNumber) & get) {
  (a1, a2, tf, t1, t2) => complete(apiController.apiGetCandlesRange(a1, a2, tf, t1, t2))
}
```

But I want to change some of the parameters to be Query Parms. So the URL will follow a format like this;

```
/candles/Asset1/Asset2/timeStart=1507198441000&timeEnd=1512382501000&interval=60m
```

And pass them through to the same method (Perhaps even removing the 'm' from the minutes as the param on the method is an int)

How can change this route to do this in Scala Akka Http. The only examples I can find use Path params

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read about `parameters` here: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/parameter-directives/parameters.html

```
val candlesRange: Route = (path("candles" / Segment / Segment / )) { (a1, a2) =>
    get {
        parameters('timeStart, 'timeEnd, 'interval) { (timeStart, timeEnd, interval) => 
            complete(apiController.apiGetCandlesRange(a1, a2, timeStart, timeEnd, interval))
    }
}
```